# Pentaho Report Designer error in query

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am trying to create my first report in Pentaho Report Designer. I have created a JDBC Data Source and added a query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   (SELECT Sum(loan_receivable_detail.interest) AS interest, 
               loan_account_opening_id 
        FROM   loan_receivable_detail 
        GROUP  BY loan_account_opening_id) AS a
```

However when I save the query, it changes to:

```
SELECT
     a.*,
     sum(loan_receivable_detail.interest) AS interest,
     loan_account_opening_id AS interest
FROM
     `loan_receivable_detail`
GROUP BY
     loan_account_opening_id,
     as,
     a
```

Is there any problem in my query causing it to change like this? The syntax works well in other query analyzers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be valid, but it seems like Pentaho is having problems parsing it.

You could try to use

```
SELECT SUM(loan_receivable_detail.interest) AS interest, 
               loan_account_opening_id 
        FROM   loan_receivable_detail 
        GROUP  BY loan_account_opening_id
```

Which gives the same results as your query but without the subquery (Hopefully it will make Pentaho happy )

Comment: the query was only sample query. I need query with sub queries.

Comment: seems like pentaho is having some problems with subqueries as there are few unresolved bugs on their jira about that (i.e. http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-4360). do not know if it would help you but I would consider moving those subqueries to DB - creating some view based on your query as workaround

Comment: note those problems are only when using the wizard query designer. If you just paste your query in then Pentaho wont reformat it or do anything with it.