# SELECT ALL in a CASE inside a SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pentaho

i'm using Pentaho and I was wondering if it's possible to do some query like this :

```
SELECT Something
FROM Somewhere
WHERE (CASE WHEN condition1 = 0 THEN Option IN (Parameter) ELSE
      (Option IN (SELECT Option FROM Somewhere_else)) END);
```

If you want some precision, i want to select everything if my condition is not respected in my WHERE clause (the thing i want to select in the where is different from the original select).
Don't hesitate to ask me for my approach and of course to answer !

Thank you !

PS: The Parameter is a Pentaho parameter which represents here an array

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Using MySQL (but through Pentaho BI)

Comment: `Option in (parameter)` looks like a mistake.

Comment: Well when my condition is true, this works like a charm (it's a pentaho parameter actually which represents an array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use regular conditions:

```
SELECT Something
FROM Somewhere
WHERE (condition1 = 0 AND Option IN (Parameter))
   OR (condition1 != 0 AND Option IN (SELECT Option FROM Somewhere_else));
```

Comment: I don't know if it's because of Pentaho but this actually doesn't work (the inner SELECT returns empty)... But yeah this is the right procedure to do :)

Comment: Are you sure your inner query is right ? Cause this is standard SQL... Don't know Pentaho too much though, but it would be weird it doesn't understand that.

Comment: Well it's a basic SELECT no ? I just want to select everything is my condition is false... But if i'm doing it wrong, please tell me :)

Comment: Indeed it is, and your query is syntactically ok, but I don't know what's in your Somewhere_else table, What I meant is that it makes no sense that Pentaho could output nothing from a valid query (with a non empty target table) just because it's used as a subquery.

Comment: You know, Pentaho doesn't allow full dynamic queries so i won't be surprised if an inner query doesn't work haha. After further tests, apparently, maybe cos it's multi-threaded, my condition1 is badly updated when it's false... I mean, it seems to do the query before changing the parameter... So maybe no SQL problems (i started this way cos i'm not that good in SQL)

Comment: After googling around, found this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20903306/1679537 . Look at the comments, maybe this could help you ? I mean, google "pentaho subquery" raises more questions and errors than documentation, maybe that's a sign...

Comment: It's in the report part but thank you for your help. It's really a timing problem : when i alert my parameter, it works but when i don't, the query is updated before the parameter change (then it's a normal expecting to have an empty result set). Again, thank you for your help :)

(Though i don't know how to make it wait properly)

Answer (score 0):

You should try following,

```
SELECT Something
FROM Somewhere
WHERE 
1 = case when condition1 = 0 THEN 
       case when Option IN (Parameter) then 1 else 0 end 
    else
       case when Option IN (SELECT Option FROM Somewhere_else) then 1 else 0 end
    end
```

Comment: This one looks complicated. What does that change from my original query ? Some verification ?
(Just tested it, doesn't work, i'm sorry...)

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is irrelevant in your statement, and is pretty much irrelevant in the `WHERE` clause at all.

Use simple conditions as suggested by @X.L.Ant, or you could do some nasty joining like

```
SELECT *
FROM table a
INNER JOIN somewhere ON (option = 0 AND a.id = somewhere.id)
INNER JOIN parameter ON (option != 0 AND a.id = parameter.id)
```

Assuming your parameter is somewhat a table.

Comment: My parameter is an array (of string to be precise). But good reasoning, man, i'll adapt it in some way :)

Comment: Well, MySQL will represent your array in _some way_ as SQL doesn't have a concept of array as a datatype.

Comment: What I wanted to say is, there definitely is a way for you to _represent your array as a somwhat local table to join with_, if it's not available out of the box.

Comment: So if it's an array, i can pass it as a table ?